# Outline plot area in plotly in Python

Tags: python, plotly

I've made a figure in plotly, e.g.:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    y=[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
)
data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = dict(xaxis = dict(title = 'T (K)', showgrid=False, ticks='inside'),
                yaxis = dict(title = 'normalized intensity', showgrid=False, ticks='inside'),
                font=dict(size=18),
                )
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, auto_open=True, filename='test_fig.png')
py.image.save_as(fig, filename='test_fig.png')
```

and the figure looks like:

[image: test figure]

I'd like an outline of the plot area like so:

[image: outlined fig]

but I am unable to figure it out from the plot.ly docs so far.  Is this possible?

Comment: setting `showline=True` in each axis dictionary will give you the left and bottom lines, not sure if top and right are possible though.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

All you need is to find another well hidden Plotly attribute. In this case it is [`mirror`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-mirror).

> `mirror (enumerated: True | "ticks" | False | "all" | "allticks" )`
>
> Determines if the axis lines or/and ticks are mirrored to the opposite
>   side of the plotting area. If "True", the axis lines are mirrored. If
>   "ticks", the axis lines and ticks are mirrored. If "False", mirroring
>   is disable. If "all", axis lines are mirrored on all shared-axes
>   subplots. If "allticks", axis lines and ticks are mirrored on all
>   shared-axes subplots.

Add

```
mirror=True,
ticks='outside',
showline=True,
```

to your `xaxis` and `yaxis` `dicts` and you get the following graph.

[image]

Comment: Hah thanks.  I'd say 'well-hidden' is not a good property of methods/attributes of a programming library.

Comment: @wordsforthewise: Well to Plotly's defense, it is shown on the example pages but googling won't help you because the essential keywords are missing. https://plot.ly/python/axes/#styling-and-coloring-axes-and-the-zeroline