# Is there a way to draw borders around a figure in Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following bar chart. I would like to put it around a border. Does anyone know how to do it?

```py
data = {'Programming Languages': ['Python', 'C#', 'Java', 'Ruby', 'C++', 'C',
                     'JavaScript', 'PHP', 'TypeScript', 'Haskell', 'Closure', 'Kotlin'],
        'Responses': [12,11,10,5,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Programming Languages', 'Responses'])

df = df.sort_values(by='Responses', ascending=True)
fig = px.bar(df, x='Responses', y='Programming Languages', color_discrete_sequence=["black"])

fig.update_layout({'plot_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'},
        font=dict(size=15))

fig.write_image("../images/pl2.pdf")
fig.show()
```

Unfortunately, I cannot paste the figure as it is a pdf file.

Comment: Which color should the borders have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outline plot area in plotly in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096292/outline-plot-area-in-plotly-in-python)

Comment: Any color, actually this link does not help much, I am not sure where to change the layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True,
         linewidth=1,
         linecolor='black',
         mirror=True)

fig.update_yaxes(showline=True,
         linewidth=1,
         linecolor='black',
         mirror=True)

fig.show()
```

[image: Fig]

Comment: But this does not work for "Indicator" charts because they dont have any axes in the first place. What do we do then?

Comment: hi @JigidiSarnath, I'd be happy to take a look. It would be helpful to see an example of your question as the OP did above. Please create the question with sample data and reply here with the link.

Comment: Thank you Amance! I created a gist of a function which will return a plotly figure that displays a number given in the argument.

https://gist.github.com/skannan-maf/15f7a160ddfd42c3397fe2b286d0b1eb

NOTE: The last 2 calls to "update_axes" and "update_yaxes" were intended to draw borderlines for the chart. However, since Indicator charts do not have axes, they don't take any effect. That is the issue I was mentioning. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @JigidiSarnath It would be better to post your question here on StackOverflow, just as the OP did. This will allow countless others to learn from your question and you'll be able to get solutions from many people.

Comment: Thanks @amance. But this is the post where the solution of mirroring axis is discussed, I thought it would be most appropriate. Thats why. Anyway, Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JigidiSarnath Your situation is different. I have a solution for you once you post your question.